# Android debugging return to same place

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug, android-instant-run

Lets say that I am developing/debugging an activity that in order to reach it I need to pass 4 screens.

each time I run the app I need to start over.

I tried using instant run but it is not always working.
for now I wrote a dedicated code that automatically skips between the screen (instead of making me click manually) but this is not practical..

I cant not just open the activity because it gets information from the previous activities..

Is there a way to make android studio return to the same place when I build & run, or keep a state?

(I know that this is what instant run is for but when developing a big application it does not work too good, at least for me)

Comment: Make sure you are using Android Studio 2.2 (currently available as "RC"). With 2.2 instant run works much more often according to Google.

Comment: I am using 2.1.3 . I think 2.2 is not official yet.

Comment: Even the first beta of 2.2 was "official" by Google. Sometimes if you need a feature of a new version it is worth the risk of using beta software. BTW: "rc" is the release candidate - hence it is nearly the final stable version...

Comment: I will try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

On *previous* activity

```
intent.putExtra("passed_from_previous_activity", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

On *new* activity

```
onCreate() {
    //This way you'll also know if this activity's been reached from the previous activity or not
    if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("passed_from_previous_activity",false)) {
        //your state values here
        //i.e., the values that you receive from the previous activity
    }
}
```

If you have a hundred activities (playing devil's advocate) and you really need to start exactly from 55th activity which is tightly coupled with 53rd and 54th activity, then I suggest you have a button *for debugging purposes* that takes you to 53rd activity, and then transition to 54th and then to finally 55th.

While turning off *instant run* is another solution, you need to start from 1st activity, and have a button that magically takes you *using the small workaround mentioned above* preserving the state to 53rd activity, and do the same as said above.

Comment: but I dont have the values.. I pass a big object that comes from api. I cant just create it here, it is too hard

Comment: is it inextricably coupled? how about capture it once _from the api_ and use it for debugging? if not, you need to turn `instant run` off and begin from the first activity

Comment: This is what I do now. I have buttons that take me where I need but making them takes time.
the current activity is part of a flow like a wizard (but not a wizard)